# Not sure why closed as "opinion based"

Tags: support, closed-questions

I have a question about my Super User post: [ACPI thermal zone driver in Windows 10. Not always available](https://superuser.com/questions/1599392/acpi-thermal-zone-driver-in-windows-10-not-always-available)

My post has factual information we have found and possibility of factual answers to the questions of

1. Where can we get these drivers?
2. Why these drivers aren't available on all Windows devices. We have observed the driver being available on devices and not included on devices without observable relation to device type, Windows version number, etc.

What is opinion based about my post?

Comment: "Why these drivers aren't available on all Windows devices." - This was the reason I flagged it as seeking an opinion.  "Where can we get these drivers?" - If you can't find the driver on the Windows Catalog website, then I presume, the driver isn't entirely public.

Comment: I can think of several non-opinion answers to why the drivers aren't available such as "not all devices have the sensors that the drivers support" or "some devices use a different driver/system" or "available on Windows version X and beyond". How can I edit this question to get it opened?

Comment: By hitting "edit", but you should be adding details to the question, instead of the reasons you object to the closure of the question.  Only the first edit to the question, after it was closed, will nominate it to be reopened.  You should make that edit count.  The only edit the question recieved was before the question was closed.